# VBA code to hide/unhide multiple rows in another worksheet based on cell output from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use VBA code for the following: based on a cell output (either "TRUE" or "FALSE" in cell W20, which changes based on whether a user checks a box or not), I want rows to be hidden/unhidden on another worksheet called "Analysis" worksheet based on the code below. I right clicked the "Summary" tab where cell W20 and the checkbox are located -> view code -> wrote the code below, but it's not working. I am very new to VBA, please help, it would be very appreciated, thanks in advance

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set Target = Range("$W$20")
If Target.Value = "FALSE" Then
    Sheets("Analysis").Rows("54:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Sheets("Analysis").Rows("54:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
If Target.Value = "FALSE" Then
    Sheets("Analysis").Rows("94:95").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Sheets("Analysis").Rows("94:95").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
If Target.Value = "FALSE" Then
    Sheets("Analysis").Rows("134:135").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Sheets("Analysis").Rows("134:135").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't recognize the modification of a cell value caused by the manipulation of form controls. I assume this is because Excel links a form control to a value and applies the changes itself, therefore not considering it a user change in the spreadsheet.

In order to make your code work, you will have to move your code into a module as a click event of your form control. Click the Developer tab and then Visual Basic. Once Visual Basic is open, you will notice on the left pane that you have a list of your worksheets within a VBA Project bearing the name of your workbook and your macro is currently within one of them. Once you found it, delete the code of your macro. Then, right-click on the name of your workbook and then select Insert > Module...

On the coding pane, insert this modified code:

```
Sub NameOfYourFormControlCheckBox_Click()

Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("$W$20")

If MyRange = False Then
    Sheets("Analysis").Rows("54:55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf MyRange = True Then
    Sheets("Analysis").Rows("54:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Make sure that the name of the sub is the name of your form control (checkbox) followed by an underscore and then "click".

Hope this helps!